# Converting a String to an Int Array

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift, int

I've that type of String for example:

```
var test:String = "[1, 0, 4]";
```

And I need to convert it to an array of Int:

```
var testConverted:[Int] = [ 1, 0, 4 ];
```

Comment: You can skip trimming and stuff and go like this `let testConverted = test.characters.flatMap({String($0)}).flatMap({Int($0)})`

Comment: @Whirlwind That's pretty neat, but assumes single digit numbers, which may not be what OP wants. For example `"[10, 50, 40]"` goes to `[1, 0, 5, 0, 4, 0]`. Although I see no reason to use `flatMap` twice there, you could just do `let testConverted = test.characters.flatMap{Int(String($0))}`

Comment: @originaluser2 You are right, thanks, I was hasty and wasn't thinking about multiple digit numbers, but rather concentrated on OP's example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to trim off the start and end brackets by using `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet`, then get the array of string elements by using `componentsSeparatedByString`. Then you can finally use `flatMap` to create an array of integers from this.

For example:

```
let yourString = "[1, 0, 4]"

// trim off the start and end brackets of the string – then obtain an array of elements by using componentsSeparatedByString
let arrayOfStrings = yourString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "[]")).componentsSeparatedByString(", ")

// flatMap the arrayOfStrings to an array of integers, filtering out any strings that cannot be represented as numbers
let arrayOfInts = arrayOfStrings.flatMap{Int($0)}
print(arrayOfInts)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var test = "[1, 0, 4]"

test = test.substringToIndex(test.endIndex.advancedBy(-1)).substringFromIndex(test.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
var result = test.componentsSeparatedByString(", ").flatMap {Int($0)}
print(result) // [1, 0, 4]
```

Comment: `flatMap` would be far nicer than force unwrapping the `Int?` in the `map` ;) That way you can filter out any elements that can't be represented as numbers without crashing.

Comment: Thanks for your advice :D.