# Swift 3: Split string into Array of Int

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I'm trying to split string into Array Of integers:

```
let stringNumbers = "1 2 10"
var arrayIntegers = stringNumbers.characters.flatMap{Int(String($0))}
```

But my problem is I'm getting this output:

```
[1, 2, 1, 0]
```

When I should be getting this output:

```
[1, 2, 10]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a String to an Int Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36765670/converting-a-string-to-an-int-array)

Comment: Well you're converting every separate character into integers. All multi-digit numbers have their digits be interpreted as seperate, single-digit numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this

```
let stringNumbers = "1 2 10"
let array = stringNumbers.components(separatedBy: " ")
let intArray = array.map { Int($0)!} // [1, 2, 10]
```

Comment: Careful using `!`. While it won't cause problems with this specific string, it will crash if the string actually contains any text that can't be converted to a number.

Comment: Agreed with rmaddy

Comment: When the first number is 0, it wont be added to the final array, what to do there?

Answer (score 4):

You are converting the individual characters of the strings into numbers. First the `1`, then the space, then the `2`, then the space, then the `1`, and lastly the `0`. If course converting the space gives a `nil` with is filtered out by using `flatMap`.

You can do:

```
let stringNumbers = "1 2 10"
var arrayIntegers = stringNumbers.components(separatedBy: " ").flatMap { Int($0) }
```

This splits the original string into an array of strings (separated by a space) and then maps those into integers.

Comment: the I print you solution I'm getting "[Optional(1), Optional(2), Optional(10)]". How can I just print the array of numbers ?

Comment: `let arrayIntegers = stringNumbers.components(separatedBy: " ").flatMap{ Int($0) }`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. Updated. Forgot just using `map` will give an array of optionals in this case. And using `flatMap` leaves out any `nil` values if the string contains any text that can't be converted to a number.

Comment: you can also use this for null value **let arrayIntegers = stringNumbers.components(separatedBy: " ").flatMap{ Int($0) as? String ?? "" }**

Comment: @seggy There's no need to use `??` with `flatMap`. And `Int` will never be a `String` so it makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5 it is:

```
let stringNumbers = "1 2 10"
var arrayIntegers = stringNumbers.split(separator: " ").compactMap { Int($0) }
```

Comment: Alternative for Swift 5: `stringNumbers.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).compactMap { Int($0) }`. You can also use `.whitespacesAndNewlines` to split by newlines too.